# Regex to allow more than one dash in a word but not 2 in a row

Tags: regex

This passes so far:

```
Shawn-Shawn
```

but this does not and needs to:

```
Shawn-Shawn-Shawn
```

This is the regex I have, curious as to why an optional does not allow it even if it still end in a character

```
/^[a-z]+[\-]?[a-z]+$/i
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$/i
```

Non capturing group `(?:-[a-z]+)*` allows 0 or more matches of hyphen followed by letters 0 or more times thus allowing multiple hyphens in input separated by letters but not these cases:

1. No repeat of `-`
2. No hyphen  at sttrt or end

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG3iQ7/1)

Answer (score 1):

This might do it, it allows any number of -words to be added:

```
^[a-z]+([\-]?[a-z]+)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/aF4pL2/1

Edit: The comments below show the problem with this, I upvoted the other answer

Comment: This has a high chance of running into a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when applied to a string actually containing double `-`

Comment: @SebastianProske Would `^([a-z]+[\-])+[a-z]+$` still have that problem?

Comment: No, but it wouldn't allow `Shawn` as a match. Just take a look at @anubhavas answer, it covers that case.